# How to force "intermediate" key use in a multi-hop SSH connection with agent forwarding?

Tags: ssh

I am using a multi-hop SSH connection with agent forwarding enabled at each hop. I want to connect to a destination machine (Machine D) using the key of the preceding hop, not the one from the originating machine.

## The details:

Working on the console of Machine A I connect to Machine B with SSH (`ForwardAgent yes`):

```
Machine A  ---SSH(id_rsa_A)--->  Machine B  ---SSH(forwarded_key)--->  Machine D1
```

When I execute `ssh-add -L` (on B) I get the `id_rsa_A`. And if I connect from B to D1, it uses `id_rsa_A` for authentication.

OK, this is what I want.

---

Working on the console of Machine B I connect to Machine C with SSH  (`ForwardAgent yes`):

```
Machine B  ---SSH(id_rsa_B) --->  Machine C  ---SSH(forwarded_key)--->  Machine D2
```

When I execute `ssh-add -L` (on C) I get the `id_rsa_B`. And if I connect from C to D2, it uses `id_rsa_B` for authentication.

OK, this is what I want.

---

Now I go back to Machine A and have a two-hop SSH connection both with `ForwardAgent yes` to Machine C via B:

```
Machine A  ---SSH(id_rsa_A)--->  Machine B  ---SSH(id_rsa_B)--->  Machine C ---SSH(forwarded_key)--->  Machine D2
```

When I execute `ssh-add -L` (on C) I get the `id_rsa_A`. And when I connect to Machine D2, SSH connection uses `id_rsa_A` even though the preceding connection between B and C explicitly uses `id_rsa_B`.

This is what I want to change. Namely I want `forwarded_key` to be `id_rsa_B`.

Is it possible (and how) to force Machine C (connected from A via B) to use `id_rsa_B` for its outgoing SSH connections?

---

I even tried `ForwardAgent no` option on first connection:

```
Machine A  ---SSH(id_rsa_A)--->  Machine B
```

leaving `ForwardAgent yes` on subsequent connection:

```
Machine B  ---SSH(id_rsa_B)--->  Machine C
```

but then further connection does not use agent forwarding at all:

```
Machine C ---SSH(no_key)--->  Machine D2
```

It looks like it's only for the whole pipe between console and the currently connected machine.

Comment: Where is the `id_rsa_B` file located? It is stored on the machine B? If you would like to forward authentication with this key, you need to add it to the agent (and it might not be possible with forwarded agent) or start a new agent on machine B with the key B, which will get forwarded to the further machines. Using authentication is not always related to having the key in agent.

Comment: Yes, it's `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on Machine B and `id_rsa_A` is  `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on Machine A. But if I work on Machine B, it gets forwarded without problems (even at the same time to the same machines as with A->B->C connection).

Comment: For a test I renamed the keys so that their names do not conflict, ie. `~/.ssh/id_rsa_A` and ``~/.ssh/id_rsa_B`, but it did not change anything. I would be surprised if it did, but checked anyway.